# Configuring SLURM to use PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hpc, slurm

I recently installed SLURM 15.08.2 and PostgreSQL 9.3.10

When setting up the scheduler to use slurmdbd daemon one needs to specify th `StorageType` in slurmdbd.conf file.

The [official documentation](http://slurm.schedmd.com/slurmdbd.conf.html) states that

> StorageType
>   Define the accounting storage mechanism type. Acceptable values at present include "accounting_storage/mysql". The value "accounting_storage/mysql" indicates that accounting records should be written to a MySQL or MariaDB database specified by the StorageLoc parameter. This value must be specified.

What value do I need to specify to use force the daemon to use my postgresql database?

The verbose output of slurmdbd daemon is

```
~/slurm_projectDB/slurm-15.08.2/sbin$ ./slurmdbd -Dv
slurmdbd: error: Couldn't find the specified plugin name for accounting_storage/pgsql looking at all files
slurmdbd: error: cannot find accounting_storage plugin for accounting_storage/pgsql
slurmdbd: error: cannot create accounting_storage context for accounting_storage/pgsql
slurmdbd: fatal: Unable to initialize accounting_storage/pgsql accounting storage plugin
```

Comment: "*Acceptable values at present include "accounting_storage/mysql"* - sounds as if your **only** choice is MySQL